# jQuery - Flickr plugin with colorbox - gallery displays previous photos

Tags: jquery, colorbox, each, flickr

I'm working on a plugin to display multiple flickr photo set photos retrieved from the api in a colorbox gallery.  I've gotten *really* close (with the help of some nice SO users!)

The idea is that the user can enter html like:

```
    <div id="72157634235266773" class="thumbs"></div>   

    <div id="72157633471728555" class="thumbs"></div>
```

and the plugin handles the rest.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eBGVV/5/

My issue is that Photo Set 2 here starts at image 64 and you can use the the left arrow to see the images in Photo Set 1.  Ideally, each thumbnail image would launch a colorbox gallery of just the photos that match its photoset id.

Any ideas how to pull this off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was using the rel property incorrectly to group the photos together.  This is what worked:

```
$("a.gallery[rel=" + PhotoSetID +"]").colorbox();
```

here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eBGVV/6/